# Windows 8 and CListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-8, clistctrl

I'm currently trying to port a produce to Windows 8 (desktop mode). According to Microsoft, the product should just work, but I'm hitting an issue when using a CListCtrl call. The list control produces the list items, but no text is displayed onto the list control, just a blank document icon.

The control is an owner drawn control and the data being passed in is definitely valid, but when inserting this data into a new entry in the control, it ends up being displayed as blank. This only occurs on Windows 8..

Has anyone come across this problem, or have any ideas on what the issue could be?

Comment: No problems with fonts or anything?

Comment: Fonts are fine, I tried hard coding to the standard fonts, sizes and colours and still the same behaviour :(

Comment: I've found after some additional investigation that the data is being lost due to the following path through the code:

Comment: I've found after some additional investigation that the data is being lost due to the following path through the code: 1. Call ListBox_AddItemData() with the correct window handle and passing as lParam a pointer to my message structure, 2. The LB_ADDSTRING window message is caught but the lParam is now pointing to a different part of memory. This only happens on Windows 8, Windows 7 doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Our list control class is actually one that inherits from the CListCtrl class due to the owner drawn stuff that we require

Comment: When you pass the pointer to your message structure, is this structure allocated on the stack or on the heap?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that we were calling a ListBox_AddItemData() to push the windows message in, which worked in previous versions of Windows, but Windows 8 does not allow this.

What is actually catching this message is a ListView control. Once I switched the function calling ListBox_AddItemData() to send a custom message, being caught by the ListView control, the pointers are now correct, so it's something changed in the message cracker for Listbox_AddItemData.